# JAXB - how to indicate duplicate nodes when unmarshalling

Tags: jaxb, unmarshalling, duplicates

I have a question. Is there any way to detect duplicate nodes (with different values) in xml file?

If java class looks like this (I've just made this up for sake of simplicity):

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "PERSON")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Person {

    @XmlElement(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @XmlElement(name = "SURNAME")
    private String surname;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }
    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }
}
```

and input .xml file looks like this:

```
<person>
   <name>John</name>  
   <surname>Smith</surname>  
   <name>Jack</name>  
</person>
```

After unmarshalling process, value 'John' gets overriden by value 'Jack'.
Is there any way to detect/avoid this?
(So i can throw Exception or log occurence of this duplicate?)

Answer (score 0):

The general solution to this problem is to set your XML schema as an instance of `javax.xml.validation.Schema` on that `Unmarshaller` to ensure the XML matches the expected input.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-marshalunmarshal-schema.html

Comment: Thanks, i will look at it, but looks, that my problem is solved.  Is there any way to localize sax parse exception messages? I need to inform customer, that his XML has wrong format with some closer specification (not in english) and all exceptions/mesages are of type SAXException with different message.

Comment: @MichalVelecky - The localization of the error messages will depend upon the implementation of the parser used.